# Excel Decimal Places from MS Query

Tags: excel

Here is a confusing thing in Excel - I have looked around on Stackoverflow and other sites and cannot find a solution.

I extract a 3 decimal number from a text file (using VB.NET, but I don't think that is involved in the problem).  I store this value as a single in and Access database - (I have tried double as well.)

I use MS Query to bring these 3 decimal place values into Excel.  Although the starting text is clearly 3 decimals, in Excel there are added decimal places.  For example:

```
Text file value: 
0.027
Stored in Access:
0.027
Value in Excel:
0.0270000007003546
```

I round the values to avoid confusion for others, but this can cause problems with some other programming that I do.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem to be related to this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113

> When storing numbers, a corresponding binary number can represent
>   every number or fractional number. For example, the fraction 1/10 can
>   be represented in a decimal number system as 0.1. However, the same
>   number in binary format becomes the repeating binary decimal 
>       0001100110011100110011 (and so on)
>       and can be infinitely repeated. This number cannot be represented in a finite (limited) amount of space. Therefore, this number is
>   rounded down by approximately -2.8E-17 when it is stored.

If would force Excel by setting an explicit rounding to solve the problem as both you and the documentation suggest.